# Split SQL Column into Multiple Rows by Regex Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-express

I'm in the middle of converting an NTEXT column into multiple records. I'm looking to split the original column by new line or json object. It's a unique scenario, to be sure, but outside of a sql environment this regex correctly matches everything I need from the original column:

`({(.*)(.*\r\n)*?})|(.+\r\n)`.

If I have a record with a column that has the value:

```
Foo bar baz
hello world
{
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'foo'
}
{
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
}
```

I want to break it into multiple records:

```
| ID | Text         |
---------------------
|  1 | Foo bar baz  |

|  2 | hello world  |

|  3 | {            |
|    |   foo: 'bar' |
|    |   bar: 'foo' |
|    | }            |

|  4 | {            |
|    |   foo: 'foo' |
|    |   bar: 'bar' |
|    | }            |
```

Any easy way to accomplish this? It's a SQL Express server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a split/parse function

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='Foo bar baz
hello world
{
  foo: ''bar'',
  bar: ''foo''
}
{
  foo: ''foo'',
  bar: ''bar''
}'

Select ID=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
      ,Text = B.RetVal
 From (Select RetSeq,RetVal = IIF(CharIndex('}',RetVal)>0,'{'+RetVal,RetVal) from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'{')) A
 Cross Apply (
               Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,IIF(CharIndex('{',A.RetVal)>0,char(1),char(10)))
             ) B
 Where B.RetVal is Not Null
```

Returns

```
ID  Text
1   Foo bar baz
2   hello world
3   {
     foo: 'bar',
     bar: 'foo'
    }

4   {
     foo: 'foo',
     bar: 'bar'
    }
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```

Comment: Really great answer! Appreciate the help. I've just realized the data I'm manipulating has some nested json data as well (pooh). How might you manipulate the UDF to ignore `{` that doesn't immediately follow a new line? (All nested json data has at least two spaces before it.)

Comment: @SamThornton  I was worried about that.  Let me noodle it a bit.

Comment: @SamThornton FYI, the UDF is just a parser.   1,001 uses.   Can you supply a more robust JSON string?

Comment: Oh, yes. I meant to ask for a shift in the from query--I realize the UDF is just the parser!. Here's a more robust json string:

Comment: {
  foo: 'foo'
  subprocesses: [
    {
      bar: 'bar'
    }
  ]
}

Comment: (I can also edit the original question, but I didn't want it to look like you hadn't correctly answered my original question)

Comment: @SamThornton I'll need an 45min to an hour - My turn to watch for Trick or Treaters

Comment: Haha, sounds great. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @John Cappelletti. Any thoughts on how I might handle json objects that have nested objects? :)

Comment: @SamThornton I do.  Sorry I didn't get back to you last night.  For the nested objects, do you want as a separate row, and how do you want the group to be displayed.   Would you mind if the JSON was transformed into a hierarchy structure?

Comment: I'd prefer the results to be a individual row for each parent object, leaving the children alone.

Comment: So { foo: [ { bar: "bar", baz: "baz" } ] } would stay as such in a single row.

Comment: FWIW, I figured it out, but thanks so much for your time! Given the state of my data I realized I can just initially parse on `char(10)+'{'`

Comment: @SamThornton Well done!  Sorry I got pulled away.  Month-End reporting cycle and they needed a quick process change