# Extract delimited data from a column into multiple rows with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

I have a column of data in a SQLite database indicating which sensor data is included in that row. The problem is that there can be multiple sensors updated at a time, delimited by | and in no guaranteed order.

What I have in my table `Data`:

```
*-------*----------------------*
* RowID * Sensor               *
*-------*----------------------*
*    1  * 'EEG|Eyetracker|GSR' *
*    2  * 'Eyetracker|GSR'     *
*    3  * 'GSR|EEG'            *
*    4  * 'EEG|EyeTracker'     *
*-------*----------------------*
```

I want to extract all unique sensor names, like so:

```
*------------*
* Sensor     *
*------------*
* EEG        *
* Eyetracker *
* GSR        *
*------------*
```

And then replace the single Sensor column with a table with a foreign key to that row:

```
* -----------*------------*
* Sensor     * Data.RowID *
* -----------*------------*
* EEG        * 1          *
* Eyetracker * 1          *
* GSR        * 1          *
* EyeTracker * 2          *
* GSR        * 2          *
* GSR        * 3          *
* EEG        * 3          *
* EEG        * 4          *
* EyeTracker * 4          *
* -----------*------------*
```

I've looked around, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351534/split-sql-column-into-multiple-rows-by-regex-match) are specific to SQL Server, not SQLite. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659643/split-a-string-into-rows-using-pure-sqlite?noredirect=1&lq=1)*is* pure SQLite, but is not actually what I am looking for.

I think this may be a use-case for CTE's, but I don't know how I would go about using a CTE for this.

Comment: This is easy to do in pretty much any other language, e.g., Python. Why do you think that you need to do this in SQLite?

Comment: I am working with data imported from massive CSV files, so I prefer using SQL and letting the database figure out the details of processing it. I once processed a 3.5TB dataset in pure python, and am very keen on solutions that avoid repeating that experience.

Comment: What's wrong with `for rowid, names in db.execute("select rowid, sensor from data"): for name in names.split('|'): print(rowid, name)`?